# How do I report to a ProgressBar when working with BackgroundWorker?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have in form1 a progressBar1 and BackgroundWorker and I when clicking the button to create the avi file I want it to report to the progressBar according to the avi file creation progress.

This is the class where I create the avi file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AviFile;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class CreateAvi
    {
        public static void AviMovie(FileInfo[] FileNames)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(FileNames[0].FullName);
            AviManager aviManager =
                new AviManager(@"c:\temp\new.avi", false);
            VideoStream aviStream =
                aviManager.AddVideoStream(false, 25, bitmap);
            int count = 0;
            for (int n = 1; n < FileNames.Length; n++)
            {
                if (FileNames[n].Length > 0)
                {
                    bitmap =
                       (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(FileNames[n].FullName);
                    aviStream.AddFrame(bitmap);
                    bitmap.Dispose();
                    count++;
                }
            }
            aviManager.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

In form1:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            CreateAvi.AviMovie(allfiles);
        }
```

Progress:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Completed:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

This is what I did in form1:

This is the method in CreateAvi class I changed it so it will get also the backgroundworker from form1 (Called the variable bgw1):

```
public static void AviMovie(FileInfo[] FileNames,BackgroundWorker bgw1)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(FileNames[0].FullName);
            AviManager aviManager =
                new AviManager(@"c:\temp\new.avi", false);
            VideoStream aviStream =
                aviManager.AddVideoStream(false, 25, bitmap);
            int count = 0;
            for (int n = 0; n < FileNames.Length; n++)
            {
                if (FileNames[n].Length > 0)
                {
                    bitmap =
                       (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(FileNames[n].FullName);
                    aviStream.AddFrame(bitmap);
                    bitmap.Dispose();
                    count++;
                    int pctDone = count * 100 / FileNames.Length;
                    bgw1.ReportProgress(pctDone);
                }
            }
            aviManager.Close();
        }
```

Then in form1 I changed in the dowork event so it will get the backgroundworker1:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            CreateAvi.AviMovie(allfiles,backgroundWorker1);
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            label9.Text = getallfiles[e.ProgressPercentage].FullName;
        }
```

So the progressBar really get to 100% to the end. However, in label19 I see only until file 000101.jpg and in this idrectory there are 167 files the last one is 000167.jpg

getallfiles is `FileInfo[]`
And in the form1 constructor I did:

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(mainDirectory);
getallfiles = directory.GetFiles("*.jpg");
```

And I see that getallfiles contain 167 files. How can I report to the label the files names that are process ?

Comment: You could create a Method on form1 that updates the value of your ProgressBar (potentially selfinvoking). Then eigther access it or refactor your CreateAviClass so that it accepts a delegate to that method, which you could call from your then non static AviMovie method. *Edit:* or just use the ReportProgress method of the Backgroundworker as suggested by DGibbs

Comment: Look at my questin please updated it with what i tried reporting the files names to a labe

Comment: Edited my question again before i didnt show what i changed in the createavi class i changed the method so it will get the backgroundworker1.

Comment: Updating a label will work as I suggested in my first comment. Selfinvoking Method on Form1 accessed directly or via delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ReportProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) needs to be called from the method where progress is actually occurring:

```
public static void AviMovie(FileInfo[] FileNames,BackgroundWorker bgw1)
{
   Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(FileNames[0].FullName);
   AviManager aviManager =new AviManager(@"c:\temp\new.avi", false);
   VideoStream aviStream =aviManager.AddVideoStream(false, 25, bitmap);
   int count = 0;
   for (int n = 0; n < FileNames.Length; n++)
   {
      if (FileNames[n].Length > 0)
      {
         bitmap =(Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(FileNames[n].FullName);
         aviStream.AddFrame(bitmap);
         bitmap.Dispose();
         count++;
         int pctDone = count * 100 / FileNames.Length;
         bgw1.ReportProgress(pctDone);
       }
    }
    aviManager.Close();
}
```

Also, your loop needs to start at 0--you are skipping the first element in `FileNames`.

**EDIT:** In your background worker's `ProgressChanged` event, you can't use `e.ProgressPercentage` for your array index, you have to work backward from the percent to get the index:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) {
   progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
   int fileIndex = e.ProgressPercentage * FileNames.Length/100;
   label9.Text = getallfiles[fileIndex].FullName; 
}
```

Comment: How do i assign to a label the name of each file that is currently process ? I tried in the form1 in the backgroundworker progress event to make: label9.Text = allfiles[e.ProgressPercentage].FullName; but when the progressbar get to 100% to the end i see only file 000101.jpg and the last file in the directory is 000167.jpg

Comment: C-Pound look at my questin please updated it with what i tried reporting the files names to a label.

Comment: I also saw that FileNames in CreateAvi class are also contain 167 files. So why i see only 101 files in the progress report ?

Comment: Edited my question again before i didnt show what i changed in the createavi class i changed the method so it will get the backgroundworker1.

Comment: @user3756594: Changing the question after it is answered can invalidate the answer.  I would suggest asking a single question, getting an answer and accepting it, and then if you have another question, ask it separately (referring to the original question if necessary).

Answer (score 1):

By using [ReportProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
private void DoWork()
{
    // Calculate percent done
    backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(percentageComplete);
}
```

This will trigger the `backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged` event that you have where you can update the UI safely.

Comment: DGibbs look at my question updated with what i done so far but it's not working.

Comment: The way you tried it you report your progress only after you're done with the `AviMovie`

Comment: Well, for a start you aren't calculating a percentage value... You need to report progress from inside `AviMovie` too. You're reporting it after the operation is complete.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the body of AviMovie() into bgw_DoWork(), and add these lines to the top of the body:

```
FileInfo fileInfo = (FileInfo[])e.Argument;
int steps = fileInfo.Length;
BackgroundWorker bgw = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
```

Add this line at the end of the for loop:

```
bgw.ReportProgress((int)(100 / steps) * n, null);
```

And start the worker with this:

```
bgw.RunWorkerAsync(FileNames); //FileNames is of course the array
```

There are other ways to do it of course, but this is probably what I would do.